# Override virtual protected method that is a friend of another class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, friend

Basically, I want to somehow simulate friendship inheritance with the restriction that it can only happen from inside a certain method.

So essentially, this is what I want

```
class A; // Forward declaration
class Base{
   friend class A; // friend declaration so that A is able to see protected methods

   protected:
   virtual void method() {// some definition, might also be pure virtual}

}

class Derived : public Base{
     A aObj;
     void method(){//override the one in base and also gain access to aObj private members.}
     public:
     //public interface
} 


class A {
    int var;
    friend void Base::method(); 
    public:
      // public interface
}
```

is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Please read the question, I am not interested in calling `method` from inside A, I want to allow derived classes of `base`to access A's private members from within specific methods.

Comment: Why do you put so many restrictions?

Comment: Because I only want derived classes of base to have access to A's private members without having to manually insert a friend declaration into A every time I derive from Base

Comment: In derived class, `A` member have to be defined as `A*` to avoid the `non complete class` compiler's error.

Comment: Not sure I understand 100% what you are looking for, I just posted a possible answer, do not hesitate to tell that this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
class Base {
   friend class A; 
   protected:
   virtual void method() = 0;
   std::tuple<int> GetAProperties(const A& a) {     
        // You can change the tuple params
        // as per your requirement.
        return std::make_tuple(a.var);
   }
}

class Derived : public Base {
    A aObj;
    void method() override {
        auto objProperties = GetAProperties(aObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: better than my sol

Comment: It would be even better with `auto GetAProperties... return std::forward_as_tuple(a.var)`

Answer (score 0):

You could get pointer to private's `A` member in `Base`, and then pass these member pointers to the `Derived`:

```
class A; // Forward declaration
class Base{
   friend class A; // friend declaration so that A is able to see protected methods

   private:
   void method(A&);
   virtual void do_method(A& a,int A::* var) {// some definition, might also be pure virtual
     (a.*var)++;
   }

};
class A{
    int var;
    friend void Base::method(A&);
};
class Derived : public Base{
     A aObj;
     virtual void do_method(A& a,int A::* var) {// some definition, might also be pure virtual
     a.*var+=2;
   }
     public:
     //public interface
};

void Base::method(A& a){
       do_method(a,&A::var);
   }
```

NB: do not use it on the critical pass!!